# Embind pass lambda function as callback parameter

Tags: javascript, c++, lambda, emscripten

I would like to create a function, which calculates something. And after it's finished, it calls the callback function.

```
void calculate(int param1, ..., std::function<void(void)> callback) {
    //code...
    callback();
}
```

The binding of the function is created using `Embind`:

```
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    function("calculate", &calculate);
}
```

But if I try to call `Module.calculate(0, ..., function(){/*...*/})` I get this error:

```
UnboundTypeError: Cannot call calculate due to unbound types: NSt3__18functionIFvvEEE
```

Comment: There is a thread about this on the emscripten GitHub, looks like it is possible using embind.
https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/4927

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it's the only way, but to pass callbacks from Js -> C++, I've had to

- Not use `std::function`, but raw function pointers
- Use [`Runtime.addFunction`](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-call-function-pointers-from-c) to get a C++ function pointer for a Javascript function, and pass that into the C++ world instead of trying to pass a Javascript function directly.
- Not use `EMBIND`, but rather the [`cwrap`/`ccall` API](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap).

For your example, simplifying the interface slightly so only the callback is passed from JS -> C++, the C++ could look like the following:

```
extern "C" {

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void calculate(void (*callback)()) {
  callback();
}

}
```

The Javascript to create the callback function pointer could look like

```
var callbackPointer = Module.Runtime.addFunction(function() {
  console.log('In the callback');
});
```

and to call the function, passing the pointer (as a "number"):

```
Module.ccall('calculate', 'number', ['number'], [callbackPointer]);
```

and then compiling making sure to reserve room for the function pointer:

```
em++ app.cpp -s RESERVED_FUNCTION_POINTERS=1 -o app.js
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But what if my `calculate` function is a class method, and I would like to have more instances at a time?

Comment: You should be able to create the C++ objects and pass raw pointers to them to Javascript. A static`calculate` function could then take, along with the function pointer of the callback, a pointer to one of these objects. It will then dereference the object pointer, and call its instance `calculate` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can now do it like this:

```
void calculate(int param1, ..., emscripten::val callback) {
    callback();
}
```

The `EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS` is unchanged.

The callback can even take parameters, provided they are of supported/declared types (e.g. if you pass an `std::vector<blah>` parameter to the callback, make sure you've used `register_vector<blah>()`.)

Comment: This is the most convenience way, I write a sample can refer [sdk_web_assembly](https://github.com/AlanLi7991/cmake-tutorial-sample/blob/master/08-cross_platform/cmake/wasm/src/sdk_web_assembly.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scapix](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix) to pass parameters like `std::function`, `std::vector`, `std::map`, etc.

In addition to generating bindings automatically, [Scapix](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix) also adds conversion layer for (arbitrarily nested) common C++ Standard Library types.

Disclaimer: I am the author of [Scapix Language Bridge](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix).